How to Ensure Compatibility of MinGW-Compiled DLLs on 32-Bit and 64-Bit Windows Systems?
I'm creating two proxied DLLs for wintrust.dll: one for 32-bit systems and another for 64-bit systems, using the gcc compiler from the MinGW64 and MinGW32 toolchains. The goal of these DLLs is to mimic the original wintrust.dll, with the WinVerifyTrust function always returning success.
Current Setup
wintrust_proxy.def:
EXPORTS
WinVerifyTrust @1
ComputeFirstPageHash=wintrust.ComputeFirstPageHash @2
CryptCATVerifyMember=wintrust.CryptCATVerifyMember @3
CryptSIPGetInfo=wintrust.CryptSIPGetInfo @4
CryptSIPGetRegWorkingFlags=wintrust.CryptSIPGetRegWorkingFlags @5
; rest of the wintrust.dll functions…

wintrust_proxy.c:
#include <windows.h>

// Define Success as 0
#define WINVERIFYTRUST_SUCCESS 0

// Define the function signature based on the original WinVerifyTrust
WINAPI LONG WinVerifyTrust(
    HWND hwnd,
    GUID *pgActionID,
    LPVOID pWVTData
) {
    // Return Success enum value
    return WINVERIFYTRUST_SUCCESS;
}

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(
    HMODULE hModule,
    DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
    LPVOID lpReserved
) {
    switch (ul_reason_for_call) {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}

compile.bat:
@echo off
setlocal

REM Switch to mingw32 bin folder (32-bit environment)
set "PATH=C:\msys64\mingw32\bin\"
gcc "wintrust_proxy.c" "wintrust_proxy.def" -o "wontrust.dll" -shared -static-libgcc -Wl,--enable-stdcall-fixup

REM Switch to mingw64 bin folder (64-bit environment)
set "PATH=C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\"
gcc "wintrust_proxy.c" "wintrust_proxy.def" -o "womtrust.dll" -shared -static-libgcc

pause
endlocal

This setup outputs two DLL files: womtrust.dll for 64-bit systems and wontrust.dll for 32-bit systems.
How can I ensure that these DLL files will work on other older/newer Windows systems without requiring extra dependencies? Additionally, how can I confirm that both the 64-bit and 32-bit versions perform as intended?
I have checked both DLLs with a dependency tool and verified that they only seem to rely on standard DLLs located in the system32 and syswow64 folders, respectively. I've also used rundll32 to call some functions to confirm their existence, but I still have doubts about whether I am achieving my goals correctly, especially since this is my first experience compiling DLLs and using MSYS2.

I think WinVerifyTrust needs WINAPI for the correct calling convention on 32bit.

If it's just C code, then why do you use g++ instead of gcc?
Also you should probably use i686-w64-mingw32-gcc and x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc to make sure you're building for the correct target.

@ssbssa Thank you for the information! Just to confirm, should I add the line #define WINAPI __stdcall to the 32-bit version and rewrite the function declaration as extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) WINAPI LONG WinVerifyTrust? Is that correct? Also when I do this I get a message saying: warning: resolving _WinVerifyTrust by linking to _WinVerifyTrust@12 I am not quite sure what this means.

You don't need to define WINAPI yourself, that's already done in windows.h. The @12 is part of the stdcall name decoration , see here for details. Also, if you use an EXPORTS file, you don't need to declare your function as dllexport. And lastly, once you remove the extern "C", there actually isn't any C++ code here.

@ssbssa Thank you for the helpful explanation! I’ve now created two separate C files for the 32-bit and 64-bit versions, with the only difference being that the 64-bit version doesn't use the WINAPI calling convention. Additionally, I've added the -Wl,--enable-stdcall-fixup flag for the 32-bit compilation to remove warnings. I’ve updated my post to reflect these changes.

You don't need 2 C files for this, WINAPI is automatically defined to empty for 64-bit.

@ssbssa thank you for letting me know, I've updated the post to include a single C file.
